# selecting pseudo-elements with mootools

Tags: javascript, css, mootools, css-selectors

Using MooTools,is it possible to select elements generated using the css pseudo-selectors ':before' and ':after'? Specifically, I'm defining the element below, and trying to adjust its height with javascript, but I can't get a reference to the element so I'm unable to modify it.

```
.stuff:before {
    width: 100px;
    height: 36px;
    background: blue;
    content: "";
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but i think you can't access those property. And it's not because of MooTools.

The generated content from the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes are not part of the DOM tree. So it's not accessible from JavaScript. At all.

That said, the browser uses it to render the page, so in fact, it knows them internally. This will possibly become accessible in the future with the [Shadow DOM](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/) feature.

Comment: i believe this question was asked a while back and it got the same/similar answer so this sounds about right.

Comment: Correct, generated content is not part of the DOM. You can compare them to mirages: you know, the oasis in the desert that isn't there.

Comment: Hm, that's disappointing, but at least it makes sense now. Thanks.